# webpack can't find module if file named jsx

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

As I write webpack.config.js like this

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

And in `index.jsx` I import a `react` module `App`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './containers/App';

let rootElement = document.getElementById('box')
render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
)
```

I find if I named module app in `App.jsx`, then webpack will say in `index.jsx` can't find module `App`, but if I named named module app in `App.js`, it will find this module and work well.

So, I'm confuse about it. In my `webpack.config.js`, I have writed `test: /\.jsx?$/` to check file, but why named `*.jsx` can't be found?

[image]

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Webpack doesn't know to resolve `.jsx` files implicitly. You can specify a file extension in your app (`import App from './containers/App.jsx';`). Your current loader test says to use the babel loader when you explicitly import a file with the jsx extension.

or, you can include `.jsx` in the extensions that webpack should resolve without explicit declaration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  }
};
```

For Webpack 2, leave off the empty extension.

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
}
```

Comment: For webpack 4, I found that i needed to put this in one of the `rule`s that were listed under `module`... `{ module: { rules: [ { test: /\.jsx?$/, resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] }, include: ... } ] } `

Comment: @mrrogers I've searched everywhere for this! I tip my hat to you sir!

Comment: thank you sooo much! I was looking for that for hours!

Comment: @mrrogers Consider promoting your comment to an answer :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderVarwijk.  Good idea.  I myself have gone back to these comments to remember what I had to do :)

Comment: @mrrogers Thank you! This solution also works for webpack 5!

Answer (score 48):

In the interest of readability and copy-paste coding. Here is the webpack 4 answer from [mr rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657639/mr-rogers) comment in this thread.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
      },
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: From 4.36.1 to be precise. Here's the doc https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleresolve

Answer (score 29):

Adding to the above answer,

The ***resolve*** property is where you have to add all the file types you are using in your application.

Suppose you want to use ***.jsx or .es6*** files; you can happily include them here and webpack will resolve them:

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx", ".es6"]
}
```

If you add the extensions in the ***resolve*** property, you can remove them from the import statement:

```js
import Hello from './hello'; // Extensions removed
import World from './world';
```

Other scenarios like if you want coffee script to be detected you should configure your **test** property as well like:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'       
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: 'coffee-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.coffee')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.coffee'] 
  }
};
```

Comment: In WebPack 3.4, you can't use resolve.extension with value empty. 

This will cause an exception in the compilation:

"Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty."

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the comments on the answer from @max, for webpack 4, I found that I needed to put this in one of the rules that were listed under module, like so:

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [ 
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
        },
        include: ...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify, that bundle.js is being generated without errors (check the Task Runner Log).

I was getting 'can't find module if file named jsx' due to the syntax error in html in component render function.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue with imports while building my typescript project having the  following `webpack` dependencies:

```
"webpack": "^5.28.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
```

So, I had a `App.tsx` file present in the correct path and exported with named export. But, `yarn build` was failing with `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/app/sample_proj/src'`. The relevant code for this error is: `import {App} from './App';`. To fix this, I had to add `.tsx` under `webpack` known extensions. Sample entry from `webpack.config.js` is :

```
 module.exports = {
       ......
       resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
        }
     }
```

Also, for this error, it does not matter, if the imports are default or named. `webpack` only needs to know the kind of file extensions it should deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue, and was able to resolve using **resolve** property.

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        filename:  'bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

As You can see I have used .jsx in there which resolved following error

ERROR in ./src/app.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

For Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions

Answer (score -5):

I found restarting my server fixed this issue. simply run

```
npm start
```

Comment: While restarting your server should always be tried, that is only restarting the server and not dealing with the current problem.

Comment: In fact this solution solved my problem. For a create-react-app application where changing webpack code is not an option, this was the solution.