# Load .jsx files with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I have a problem with loading `.jsx` files using `webpack`.
I have this `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./static/js/storage/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: './static/js/storage/public/',
        publicPath: "public/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
            query: {
                plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: "react-hot!babel",
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
        }
    ]
}
};
```

And I have this packages for my application:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1"
},
    "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
}
```

And when i try to run webpack in console i have this error:

> Module parse failed:
>   /static/js/storage/src/components/StorageApp.jsx
>   Unexpected token (12:12) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

My webpack can not load jsx files. I think that problem is in my jsx loader. But I do not know what the exact problem.

I try to use react-hot, babel loader and jsx-loader with presets and without but error is the same in all cases.
This loaders don't work to:

```
test: /\.jsx$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
},
```

Can someone help with this problem?

Comment: It's failing because of that `exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]` based on the error. You could try removing `/public/` from the list to see if that fixes the issue. I prefer to maintain `include` over `exclude` myself (whitelist over blacklist) as that reads better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack can't find module if file named jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678314/webpack-cant-find-module-if-file-named-jsx)

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by adding `.jsx` post-fix to each of my imported components, like so:

```
import Somthing from './Something.jsx'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
            query: {
                plugins: ["react-hot-loader/babel", 'transform-runtime'],
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: this says: `webpack: Property 'loaders' is not allowed`

Answer (score -1):

As you have excluded the 'public' folder in your webpack setting, the compiler fails to parse the .jsx file.

Update below line your webpack file

```
exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/],
```

to

```
exclude: [/node_modules/],
```

for both .js and .jsx loaders.