# Webpack won't resolve modules without .jsx extension despite resolve being set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

If I add `.jsx` to `require('./StringOption')` it works but I thought the `resolve` section of my webpack.config.js is supposed to allow me to require with no extension. What am I doing wrong?

Also why do I need `./` infront when it resides in the same directory as index.jsx?

### Error message after running webpack:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'StringOption' in /Users/Mike/packages/chrome-extension-options/src
 @ ./src/index.jsx 5:19-42
```

### index.js:

```
'use strict'

var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
var StringOption = require('./StringOption');

ReactDOM.render(<StringOption id="test" name="Test" />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

### webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'jsx-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '*.js', '*.jsx']
    }
};
```

### Directory structure:

```
- src/
  - index.jsx
  - StringOption.jsx
- dist/
  - index.js
  - react.js
  - react-dom.js
```

Comment: Have you tried   `resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  }` See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678314/webpack-cant-find-module-if-file-named-jsx

Comment: @alexi2 you're a genius. Thank you. I saw that post but failed to notice that they hadn't put asterisks. It works now that I have removed them.

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all `./StringOption` says that it should search in the same directory. Unlike other places we need to specify from where we need to import a file in react jsx.

**Secondly**,

In resolve you need not use resolve explicitly, just use `babel-loader` or else use resolve as

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

or

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

include the following in your webpack.config.js so that you need not to worry about js and jsx extension.

```
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            // include: __dirname + '/src',
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react','es2015']
            }
       }]
```