# React.createElement: type should not be null with Meteor, TrackerReact, React-mounter and FlowRouter

Tags: reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I have this route,

```
FlowRouter.route('/dashboard',{
name: 'dashboard',
action(){
    mount(MainLayout, {
        content: (<AW />)
    })
}
});
```

I imported the AW file.

```
import React from 'react';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import UA from './UA.jsx';
export default class AW extends TrackerReact(React.Component){
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    componentWIllUnmount() {
    }
render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <UA />
        </div>
    )
    }
}
```

If I removed the `<UA />` it is working. If I placed `<UA />`, it is not working. 
The error is React.createElement: type should not be null,undefined,boolean, or number.

I tried some editing on the UA file. But unfortunately, nothing works.

Here is the UA file.

```
import React from 'react';

class UA extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(

        <div>hi</div>
    )
}
}
export default UA;
```

Comment: This means something is wrong with your import.

Comment: I don't get it. There is nothing wrong in my codes provided above?

Comment: If you remove the `<UA />` and it works it means that you're not importing from the right place.

Comment: Could it be that your webpack isn't configured to load .jsx files?  You could try renaming to .js, or setting it up as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678314/webpack-cant-find-module-if-file-named-jsx  P.S. - .jsx file extension is fine, but not really recommended by Facebook https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/87#issuecomment-234627904