# Why do I have this error in my React Native project?

Tags: react-native, webstorm, apple-m1

Need help. An error occurs during import:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, JavaScript assumes imports without a file extension to end in .js

So you're looking for a file at './src/pages/HomeContainer.js'
This file doesn't exist.
Changing the file extension of HomeContainer to .js will fix the issue or by changing your imports to include the .jsx file extension.

```
import React from 'react'; 
import HomeContainer from '.src/pages/HomeContainer.jsx';
```

If you don't want to add .jsx on your import you could add resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] } to your webpack.config.
(From Francesco Orsi's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62638083/15067557)

```
// ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src'),
                // loader: 'babel',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"],
                    plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
// ...
```