# Whats the difference between import from xxx.vue and from xxx?

Tags: vue.js

I have a `HelloWorld.vue` in my conponents.

In `main.js`, import it:

```
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

I see many Vue projects, it is import by this type, there is no `.vue` suffix:

```
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld
```

Is there difference between the two ways to import?

Comment: See the top answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678314/webpack-cant-find-module-if-file-named-jsx - while it deals with `.jsx`, it details how Webpack can be told to look for certain extensions automatically. Basically, your Webpack config says "look for .vue files". There's no functional difference between the two - use what you prefer.