# babel-register relative jsx imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-register

I want to use babel-register to run a node app that serves a react app (server side rendering).

I am using it like this:

```
require('babel-register')({
  extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
  cache: false,
  ignore: /\/(build|node_modules)\//,
  presets: ['env', 'react-app'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./app'],
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
      },
    ],
    'syntax-dynamic-import',
    'dynamic-import-node',
    'react-loadable/babel',
  ],
});
```

The thing is, when I want to import a relative jsx file without the extension (suppose a Checkout.jsx file) like

```
import Checkout from './Checkout';
```

it imports an empty object `{}`. If I add the .jsx extension to the import like

```
import Checkout from './Checkout.jsx';
```

it works and imports the React component.

Any ideas why without the extension it not work?

Thanks!!

Comment: you should try this, it may work for you "import {Checkout} from './Checkout';"

Comment: also chekout this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678314/webpack-cant-find-module-if-file-named-jsx